# If $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, then must $\mathcal{O}_K$ contain $\alpha$, and conversely?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Suppose $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = n > 1.$ Then must its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ contain $\alpha$? I think it must, and here is my reasoning: suppose it did not. Now $K$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\mathbb{Q} \cap \mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z},$ so this means $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z},$ hence $K = \mathbb{Q},$ a contradiction as the degree of the extension is greater than $1.$ Is this correct?

Also, I was also wondering if the converse holds, i.e. if $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha],$ then is $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)?$ I believe the same reasoning (that $K$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal{O}_K$) gives us this result again?

Comment: Why do you say in this case $\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathbb{Z}$ implies $\mathcal{O}_{K}=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What happens with $\alpha=\sqrt2/100$ and $n=2$?

Comment: @Shoutre I thought that because $\mathcal{O}_K$ doesn't contain $\alpha,$ but $\{1,\alpha\}$ generates $K$ as a $\mathbb{Q}-algebra,$ so $\mathcal{O}_K$ lies inside $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm not sure if this is correct though..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah.. then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ would be $x^2 - 2/10000 \notin \mathbb{Z}[x]$, so it would not be in $\mathcal{O}_K$..

Comment: Correct. Yet $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2/100)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K = K \cap \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ (the algebraic integers)

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is the smallest ring containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$. Its field of fraction is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, ie. containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$, ie. containing  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$, ie. $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Comment: Also even if $\alpha= 2 i$ is an algebraic integer, we have $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} = \mathbb{Z}[i] \ne  \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$, then you can multiply or divide $\alpha$ by elements $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that the result is or is not in $\mathcal O_K$, as you wish.  You can see this by combining four facts:

> $\bullet$ $0 \neq c \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(c \alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.
>
> $ \bullet$ If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $\mathcal O_K$, and $x \in K$, let $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(x)$ be the largest integer $m$ such that $x \in \mathfrak p^m$.  Then $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(xy) = \nu_{\mathfrak p}(x) + \nu_{\mathfrak p}(y)$.
>
> $\bullet$ If $x \in K$, then $x \in \mathcal O_K$ if and only if $\nu_{\mathfrak p}(x) \geq 0$ for all primes $\mathfrak p$.
>
> $\bullet$ If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime of $\mathcal O_K$, then $\mathfrak p \cap \mathbb{Z} \neq 0$.  In particular, $\mathfrak p \cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime number $p$.

So, you can always write $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for *some* $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$.  For such $\alpha$, you always have $\mathcal O_K \supseteq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.  A more interesting question is whether it is always possible to choose $\alpha$ so that these rings are equal (e.g. for quadratic extensions this is possible, the Gaussian integers satisfy $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{Q}[i]} = \mathbb{Z}[i]$).  The answer is surprisingly no!

To your second question (as I indicate in the previous paragraph, this is not a true *converse*: if $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$, then you only have $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subseteq \mathcal O_K$, not necessarily equal), the answer is yes.

In general, if $R$ is an integral domain with quotient field $K$, and $x$ is an element in a field $L$ containing $K$, then the quotient field $E$ of $R[x]$ is $K(x)$.   Certainly $E$ must contain the inverses of elements of $R$ as well as the inverse of $x$, so $K(x) \subseteq E$.  On the other hand, $R[x] \subseteq K[x]$, so we have $E = \textrm{quot } R[x] \subseteq \textrm{quot } K[x] = K(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The first question has been answered in the comments: no, the $\alpha$ in $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ need not be an algebraic integer.

The second question does have an affirmative answer, since $\mathcal O_K \otimes \mathbb Q \simeq K$.  For the same reason, this is true if we only require $\mathcal O_K$ to be an order in $K$, rather than the full ring of integers.  (E.g., $\mathcal O=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not the full ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$.)

Comment: By $\otimes$, do you mean the tensor product? Could you explain a bit further as I don't really know what tensoring actually does intuitively. Also, what do you mean by requiring $\mathcal O_K$ to be an "order" in $K$?

Comment: @dhk628 Yes, tensor product (over $\mathbb Z$).  In the quadratic case, where $\mathbb Z[\alpha] = \{ a + b \alpha : a, b \in \mathbb Z \}$, tensoring with $\mathbb Q$ just means the set of such elements with $a, b \in \mathbb Q$.  Alternatively, you could use that $K$ is the field of fractions of $\mathcal O_K$.  I just wrote the tensor thing because it's shorter.

Comment: The remark about orders was meant to be an aside.  Orders in $K$ are subrings of $\mathcal O_K$ that are not "too small."  (E.g., $\mathbb Z$ is too small if $n > 1$.  Technically you want to be a full lattice.)